# Check for a value onClick react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render method i render some cards that all have button and when i click on the button i want to disabled them.

Those buttons are checking if the value of the array is true and if it is it's disabling the button but this is only working when i refresh the page and i want the button to be disabled directly on click

Here is my try

```
//this is checking from my database if it include the id of the pokemon that i want to get

const check = pokemon.id
const newPoke = getPokemon.includes(check);

// Here is the button that is getting disabled only if newPoke return true

<Button isDisabled={newPoke}/>
```

Everything work correctly when i refresh the page the buttons that i clicked previously get disabled but not onClick directly.

I think after i click i have to re-check for newPoke but i'm not sure how to include it in the button

Comment: do you have any more code that you share? from looking at your snippet, it seems that you aren't using any state or any lifecycle functions/effects that would trigger the data be looked up again

Comment: please elaborate bit more, how are you getting pokemon object if its in state ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `props` to pass variable from parent to children(`Button`).
reactjs documentation states react props are [**read-only**](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

If you are planing to change the values of `newPoke` then you should rethink your structure and maybe its best to use [**states**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in your example

For example here
`<Button isDisabled="newPoke"></Button` will only be checked at initialization stage since its a react prop. but if you used state which gets updated with every new action you can have a true one-way binding and your ui would reflect data changes quickly

Answer (score 0):

store the `newPoke` in `state` and change it's value when the button is clicked. and use that value in button  `isDisabled` prop. try something like this

```
state={
isDisabled: false;
}

handleClick=(isDisabled)=>{
this.setState({isDisabled});

}

//this is checking from my database if it include the id of the pokemon that i want to get

const check = pokemon.id
const newPoke = getPokemon.includes(check);

// Here is the button that is getting disabled only if newPoke return true

return(

<Button isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(newPoke )}/>

);
```

Comment: that's just showing him how to do it and not really explaining how it solves his problem

Answer (score 0):

i think if you want get value from database you can use componentDidMount().

and your value you can save while in state. and then in function handleClick you can change this state

for example :

```
handleClick = () => {
  const value = this.state.valueFromDataBase
  this setState({valueFromDataBase: false})
}
```

and in render you declare this value state

```
render(){
  return(
    <Button defaultValue={this.state.valueFromDataBase} onCLick={this.handleClick} />
 )
}
```

please correct my answer if I am wrong in responding to your question